# React native how to re-render routeHeader when navigation.goBack()

Tags: react-native, react-router

this is my header comes from stack navigaiton header

[image: Header on notification]

and this is on none notification

[image: Header on without notification]

This is my navigaitonOptions, im using mobx for global store.
I'M setting inNotify to false when user navigates in Notificaitons page

```
const navigationOptionsBack = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  return {
    headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: "center" },
    title: <TitleSVG />,

    headerStyle: {
      shadowColor: "transparent",
    },

    headerLeft: () => (
      <Box m={5}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.goBack();
          }}
        >
          <Box
            height={50}
            width={50}
            alignItems="center"
            justifyContent="center"
          >
            <BackSVG />
          </Box>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Box>
    ),

    headerRight: () => (
      <Box m={10}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            NavigationService.navigate("Notificaitons");
          }}
        >
          <Box
            height={50}
            width={50}
            alignItems="center"
            justifyContent="center"
          >
            {STORE.isNotify == true ? <NotificationSVG /> : <NSVG />}
          </Box>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Box>
    ),
  };
};
```

Thats all ok but when **user press goBack the header is not re-renders**. How to fix it.

Thank you

in `Notifications` page

```
async componentDidMount() {
    this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {   
      Orientation.lockToPortrait(); 
      AuthStore.setPassiveNotify();
     });   
    await AuthStore.setPassiveNotify();
     Orientation.lockToPortrait();
  }
```

in **mobx STORE**

```
@action async setPassiveNotify() {
    runInAction(() => {
       this.isNotify  = false;
      
    });
  }
```

console.log

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY2Gs.png)

Comment: is ```navigaiton header``` and ```notification``` are two invidual screens?

Comment: Notifications  is another screen , header comes from stacknavigation header options

Comment: Does your observer for the mobx working perfectly can you please check it by console.log(STORE.isNotify), is that showing appropriate value as expected.

Comment: Yes it works fine and i checked in Notifications page. I'll add in minute

Comment: I added 15 min ago, header is not rerender

Comment: Am i clear or need more information